# Should I train all exercises in a muscle group sequentially?

Tags: bodybuilding, exercise-technique

If, for example I train my chest and back, and I have 2 exercises for each muscle group, lets call them chest1, chest2, back1, back2.

In this situation I usually wanted to train back1, chest1, back2, chest2.
So I can rest the back and chest between exercises.

I heard that it is better to train all exercises of a muscle group together, so that it keeps the blood pumping.

Which is preferable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you take a look at what body parts you think you need to improve, and, place priority on them by performing exercises that target those muscles **first**.   Some studies have shown that greater strength and muscular size gains are achievable with exercises placed near the beginning of a program.  A 2012 study entitled [Exercise Order in Resistance Training](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22292516) found that:

> “...the research suggests that exercises be ordered based on priority of
>   importance as dictated by the training goal of a programme,
>   irrespective of whether the exercise involves a relatively large or
>   small muscle group.”

The study goes on to say …

> “…exercise order is an important variable that should receive greater
>   attention in RT prescription. “

But, it stops short of saying that "all exercises of a muscle group" should be trained together.  Currently, I do not believe there’s any scientific evidence to suggest that assertion.

Comment: Doesn't a statement that's essentially "If you want to see gains primarily in your chest, train your chest first." pretty much imply that you want to do all of your chest exercises together? Otherwise you're not really training your chest first.

Comment: "_Otherwise you're not really training your chest first_ - I think it depends on the level of intensity, weight, number of sets, number of reps, etc. of that first exercise for the particular body part.  I've done some pretty hard training for a body part that required me to train a different muscle group, in between, and, then come back to that first body part.  I don't consider that any less effective.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this depends on your goal.
If you are looking for conditioning, continuing to work out different sets of muscles sequentially as you are allows you to move from set to set with minimal resting which keeps your heart rate up, which is **also called circuit training**. **With circuit training you will not develop explosive strength**
Again it depends on your goal, whether it is  Cardiovascular stamina, Muscular conditioning, Body building, or raw strength